# Migrating OpenGL ES 2 in android 7

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm porting my simple videogame based on OpenGL ES 2 in a different smartphone (galaxy j7):
it works fine with Galaxy note 2 (OpenGL ES 2 and Android 4.2), bad in Galaxy j7 (OpenGL ES 3.1 and Android 7)
when I draw two geometries 3D one above the other something goes wrong

I've posted  the bad effect [in this youtube video](http://youtu.be/xJHfKASQ-7k) (look for with google)

while [this](http://youtu.be/ERljT0O3vW4) is a screenshot about note2

I use the code

```
glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

and every 30 mills I call requestRender

Perhaps in android 7 `rendermode_with_dirty` doesn't work? or different settings/instruction OpenGL is needed?

1)in the draw method of the game loop

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//(draw goemetries)
GLES20.glFlush();
```

2)for each geometry 3d I do

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
//(load program -shader etc - etc..)
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: Do you request a depth buffer? Or a specific depth buffer bitrange?

Comment: Please post a complete example - it's impossible to help debug with random code snippets. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)